# How to calculate dimensions of a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I am looking for the dimensions of a 2d array. Not the fixed values assigned to the array, but the values containing integers. Example:

```
int a[][] = new int[4][5];
a[1][1] = 1;
a[1][2] = 2;
a[1][3] = -2;
a[1][4] = 0;
a[2][1] = -3;
a[2][2] = 4;
a[2][3] = 7;
a[2][4] = 2;
a[3][1] = 6;
a[3][2] = 0;
a[3][3] = 3;
a[3][4] = 1;
```

Only 3 variables are used out of 4, and 4 variables used out of 5. How can you tell what is actually there versus what is assigned to be there?

```
array.length;
array[0].length;
```

The previous code will only give you the fixed variable assigned to the array. But what if your not using all the variables? In other words I am looking for an output of 3 for columns and 4 for rows.

Comment: You can't. Array is filled with default values like `0` `false` `null` (depending on type). Since you are using `0` as proper value you can't know if rest of zeroes are default (unused) or actually set up by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you are *using* all variables in the array. Just because you haven't assigned anything to them, they are still sitting there.

If you want to determine whether or not you've assigned a value to each element in the array, you need to initialize everything to a default value, and then just compare against the default value.

A variation on that option is to declare them as `int?`, which is a nullable `int`. That would allow you to set everything to `null`, and then you'll know that the elements that are no longer `null` have had a value assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // using Integer instead of int, which is a nullable object
    Integer a[][] =  new Integer[4][5];
    int cnt1 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] != null) {
                cnt1++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt1 + " array indices are non-null.");

    // using int
    int b[][] =  new int[4][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            b[i][j] = -9999;
        }
    }

    int cnt2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            // pick a value that will never be assigned
            if(b[i][j] != -9999) {
                cnt2++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt2 + " array indices are not -9999.");
```

Comment: First loops containing `a[i][j] = null;` are redundant. `Integer a[][] =  new Integer[4][5];` is already filled with `null`s.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Even better. I'll update, not that it will matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it dynamically. Once you've initiated your matrix like that (`new int[4][5]`) you have and matrix of 0.

You must initiate the matrix ant set an invalid value to all posistions, something like -1 or whatever you wan't and iterate over it to discover the result